# How could a beechcraft fly such a long distance in LOST?

Tags: lost

We know that the beechcraft in LOST TV series took off in Nigeria in west Africa.
So how could it fly across Africa, then fly again over the Indian ocean to crash in the LOST island? (By beechcraft I mean the plane with which Mr Eko's brother took off in Nigeria )

Comment: The Island was in the South Pacific Ocean at the time. A big distance, but your flight path doesn't reflect the location properly. The Indian ocean is on the other side of Africa, not the Pacific.

Comment: Yeah you're right about the estimated position of the island. So we both agree on the long distance!

Comment: aircraft, including beechcraft also have this amazing ability to land and refuel.

Comment: @phantom42 It's a craft with an 850 mile max flight and a nearly 8000 mile distance. I have the distinct feeling that it was another case of "the island teleports around because reasons".

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer: It couldn’t, not without refueling or some supernatural agency at work.**

The max range of the [Beech 18](https://flyawaysimulation.com/downloads/files/17116/fs2004-beechcraft-18-from-tv-series-lost/) is 1650 nm. (Use [Beechcraft 350 for reference --1525 nm range)](http://txtav.com/en/range-map).,  meaning if it took off in Lagos, it would need to refuel at the latest in DR Congo, well short of the Indian ocean.

> [Judging from the map](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Beechcraft/Theories) found on the Beechcraft in "Deus Ex Machina" the plane may have been headed towards Inedbirenne Airport in Algeria (24 17' 31" N, 9 27' 08" E) which is roughly halfway between Nigeria and Tunisia, where the Polar Bear John and Ben was transported.
>
> Tunisia is a logical destination for drug smugglers, since it provides easy access to European ports. Also, Tunisia's former president, Zine El Abidine Ben Ali, was long rumored to be involved in the drug trade.

Unless the island magically moved, it never would have reached it, not without refueling. Africa is a very big place.

Comment: This is the interesting point! So there might be something in the wind!

Answer (score 1):

It's not that simple. Let's say the craft headed towards Tunisia from Nigeria. We all know the Island exit was in Tunisia. Kinda like there is a wormhole connecting b/w them. Once the plane is in the region of Tunisia, a wormhole portal could open up and transport the plane to the Island's vicinity, whereby the Island's magnetic field could do the job.

One more interesting thing is the arrival of Egyptians on the Island. Same reason. Egypt to Tunisia isn't far. Egyptians doing their own research there, found something like MIB found the orchid in 'Across the Sea'. That would transport the Egyptians to the Island.